# How to get an auth token to make a resource group

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net, azure-keyvault

I am new to azure.  Sorry if I am making a mistake.

I want to use C# to make a resource group, key vault, and a key in azure.  I am following this tutorial [native client app in azure](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-3-developing-native-client-applications/) and this github example [Git hub tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop/blob/master/TodoListClient/MainWindow.xaml.cs).  I am stuck on getting an authentication token to azure.  Both websites say you need a resource id, but how can I get a resource id if I am trying to make a resource group?

Here is my current method to get an authorization token.

```
public static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/e8cf5e65-bb37-4597-a4c8-3e7d5d781678");
        //ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "dd919bf0-8dca-4668-9ccd-f07d84b37340", clientSecret: "{application password}");
        authenticationContext.AcquireToken("resourceId", "dd919bf0-8dca-4668-9ccd-f07d84b37340", new Uri("http://google.com"), PromptBehavior.Never);

    }
```

EDIT: I am trying to use a native app, not a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Azure :-)

The "resourceId" field isn't meant to be the id of the resource group but rather the thing you're trying to authenticate to.

Based on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/) article, I believe what you need is "https://management.core.windows.net/" (look at the "Get access token in code" section).

Comment: Thank you for the welcome.  I thought that way of authenticating was only for web apps.  I thought that because only web apps can get an id and client secret (Unless I am mistaken).  Can I get a client secret with a native app?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that there were two ways of authenticating.

Comment: Needn't secret key in native app

Answer (score 0):

"resourceId" here is not a value for method AcquireToken, it is a variable, point to the identifier of the target resource that is the recipient of the requested token. Such as "https://graph.windows.net/".

We often perform specific operations against the resources exposed by the Graph API, we can read and modify objects such as users, groups, and contacts in a tenant through Graph API. More information, you can refer to Azure official documents:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-dotnet/ and [Azure AD Graph API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog)